# Object read/write in Simple Client/Server Game

Tags: java, network-programming, client-server, 2d-games

I'm trying to get a basic client/server game working. I used code I took from

www.java-gaming (DOT) org/index.php?topic=23024.0

This code worked but it did so by passing actual int values for the x and y coordinates from the client thread to the server's client thread like so:

```
me.x = in.readInt();
me.y = in.readInt();
```

Now, because I want the Player class to contain more than just x/y coordinates (Objects, not just primitives) I want to serialize the class as a whole rather than using readInt() to transfer individual primitive values. Thus I change the code in the client from:

```
out.writeInt(me.x);
out.writeInt(me.y);
out.flush();
```

to:

```
out.writeObject(me);
out.flush();
```

and the server's ClientThread code correspondingly to:

```
me = (Player) in.readObject();
```

I changed things from DataInputStream to ObjectInputStream as applicable.

However, I'm running into the following issue: after making this change to the code, movement to the left/right/up/down affects the x and y values of "me" in the client, but if I were to print out the value of me.x immediately after the Server's ClientThread line:

```
me = (Player) in.readObject();
```

Its value does not update to match the value output by the client, rather it remains at the default 50. How can I get it to properly serialize/deserialize the object?

Here are the pastebins of the code I'm running:

ServerClientThread.java: http://pastebin.com/mShgYZdf (RELEVANT CODE AT LINE 78)

```
package clientCode;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.io.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class ServerClientThread extends Thread implements Runnable{
   int playerID;
   Socket acceptedSocket;
   JTextArea textArea;
   Vector<Player> players;
   Player me;

   public ServerClientThread(Socket acceptedSocket, Vector<Player> players, int playerID, JTextArea textArea){
      super("ClientThread");
      this.acceptedSocket = acceptedSocket;
      this.players = players;
      players.add(new Player(50,50, playerID));

      if(players != null)
         System.out.println("Not Null: " + players.size());

      boolean b = false;
      for(int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++){
         if(!b){
            if(players.get(i).id == playerID){
               me = players.get(i);
               b = true;
            }
         }
      }

      this.playerID = playerID;
      this.textArea = textArea;
   }

   public void removeMeAndClose(){
      boolean b = false;
      for(int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++){
         if(!b){
            if(players.get(i).id == playerID){
               players.remove(i);
               b = true;
            }
         }
      }

      try{
         acceptedSocket.close();
      }

      catch(Exception ee){
         ee.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   public void run(){
      try{
         Socket clientSocket = acceptedSocket;
         clientSocket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
         textArea.append("Accepted. Now creating I/O.\n");
         //DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
         ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
         ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
         textArea.append("player connected. \n");
         out.writeInt(me.id);
         out.writeObject(players);
         out.flush();

         while(!clientSocket.isClosed() && clientSocket.isConnected()){
             try{
                 //OLD VERSION
                 //me.xPos = in.readInt();
                 //me.yPos = in.readInt();
                 //END OF OLD CODE

                 me = (Player) in.readObject();//THIS IS THE IMPORTANT LINE
                 System.err.println("SCT PLAYER X: " + me.xPos);//DEBUG

                 //if(players != null)
                  //System.out.println("Not Null: " + players.size());


                 textArea.append("PlayerID: " + playerID + " Players: " + players.size() + " me.x: " + me.xPos + " me.y: " + me.yPos + "\n");

                 out.reset();
                 out.writeObject(players);
                 out.flush();

                 sleep(15);
              }

              catch(Exception e){
                 removeMeAndClose();
             }
           }

      }

      catch(Exception e){
         removeMeAndClose();
      }


   }

}
```

SlickClient.java: http://pastebin.com/X26qwJ7K (RELEVANT CODE AT LINE 191)

```
package clientCode;
import org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.BasicGame;
import org.newdawn.slick.Color;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.Input;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SlickClient extends BasicGame{

    ClientThread ct;
    Vector<Player> players;
    Player me;
    int ALL_KEYS = 0xFF;
    boolean keys[];

    public SlickClient()
    {
        super("Test Online Client - by William Starkovich");
    }

    public void init(GameContainer gc) throws SlickException {
        try{
            keys = new boolean[ALL_KEYS];

            for(int i = 0; i < ALL_KEYS; i++){
                keys[i] = false;
            }

            players = new Vector<Player>();

            connect();
        }

        catch(Exception e){

        }
    }

    public void connect(){
        String ip = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input server IP.");
        ct = new ClientThread(ip);
        ct.start();
        //ct.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);

        me = ct.me;
        players = ct.players;
    }

    public void update(GameContainer gc, int delta)throws SlickException{
        controls();


        players = new Vector<Player>();

        //System.out.println("ct size: " + ct.players.size());

        me = ct.me;
        players = ct.players;
    }

    public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g) throws SlickException{
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0,0,640,480);

        for(int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++){
            g.setColor(Color.cyan);
            g.fillRect(players.get(i).xPos, players.get(i).yPos, 50, 50);
        }

        g.drawString("Players: " + players.size(), 50, 10);
    }

    public void keyPressed(int key, char c) {
        keys[key] = true;
    }

    public void keyReleased(int key, char c) {
        keys[key] = false;
    }

    public void controls(){

        me.xAccel = 0;//Acceleration defaults to zero, the player has to CHOOSE to accelerate in a direction
        me.yAccel = 0;

        if(keys[Input.KEY_UP]){
            me.yPos--;
            me.yAccel -= me.accelMagnitude;
        }

        if(keys[Input.KEY_DOWN]){
            me.yPos++;
            me.yAccel += me.accelMagnitude;
        }

        if(keys[Input.KEY_LEFT]){
            me.xPos--;
            me.xAccel -= me.accelMagnitude;

        }

        if(keys[Input.KEY_RIGHT]){

            me.xPos++;
            me.xAccel += me.accelMagnitude;
        }

        me.xVel += me.xAccel;
        me.yVel += me.yAccel;

        me.xPos += me.xVel;
        me.yPos += me.yVel;

        //System.err.println( me.xPos );

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SlickException{
        AppGameContainer app =
                new AppGameContainer( new SlickClient() );

        app.setShowFPS(false);
        app.setAlwaysRender(true);
        app.setTargetFrameRate(60);
        app.setDisplayMode(800, 600, false);
        app.start();
    }
}

class ClientThread extends Thread implements Runnable{
    Socket socket;
    Vector<Player> players;
    int playerID;
    Player me;
    //DataOutputStream out;
    ObjectOutputStream out;
    ObjectInputStream in;
    boolean loop = true;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ClientThread(String ip){
        super("ClientThread");

        try{
            players = new Vector<Player>();
            socket = new Socket(ip, 4444);
            socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
            //out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            playerID = in.readInt(); 
            players = (Vector<Player>) in.readObject();

            if(players != null)
                System.out.println("Not Null: " + players.size());

            boolean b = false;
            for(int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++){
                if(!b){
                    if(players.get(i).id == playerID){
                        me = players.get(i);
                        b = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run(){
        try{
            while(loop){
                try{
                    if(!socket.isClosed() && socket.isConnected()){
                        //OLD CODE
                        /*out.writeInt(me.xPos);
                        out.writeInt(me.yPos);*/
                        //System.err.println("##188: " + me.xPos);

                        //NEW CODE
                        out.writeObject(me);//IMPORTANT CODE HERE
                        out.flush();

                        //players = new Vector<Player>();
                        players = (Vector<Player>) in.readObject();

                        //System.out.println("size" + players.size());
                        sleep(15);
                    }

                    else
                        loop = false;

                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    socket.close();
                }  
            }



        }

        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry that there's so much code to read, I've done my best to make the important bits easier to find.

Comment: Kindly put your code here itself in a `code block` instead of a link to your code on some other place

Comment: Alright, will do. New user and I thought that would be excessive. Thanks.